# Sass - force sass engine to not format some thing

Tags: css, syntax, sass

In trying to work [around this bug](https://github.com/andrew/node-sass/issues/158) I want to place some code into my scss stylesheet that I want to render exactly how I type it `top: calc(50% - 19px);` with the spaces preserved.

I know many of these compile-to-code languages have an escape hatch where you tell the pre-processor to just use what's there verbatim. Does sass have something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution: https://github.com/hcatlin/libsass/issues/104#issuecomment-20966047

```
top: calc(unquote("50% - 19px"));
```